# Subquerys.. Porque puedo llamar a un campo y hacle un count.. pero no aplicar otra funcion de agregacion

Tags: sql, subconsultas

estoy aprendiendo SQL y me surge una pregunta.. tengo varias subquerys y se que no puede traer mas de 1 campo o eso me han dicho..

No obstante si puedo hacer esto..

```
    SELECT
  new.day,
  new.new_added_users,
  COALESCE(deleted.deleted_users, 0) AS deleted_users,
  COALESCE(merged.merged_users, 0) AS merged_users,
  (
    new.new_added_users - COALESCE(deleted.deleted_users, 0) - COALESCE(merged.merged_users, 0)
  ) AS net_added_users FROM (
    SELECT
      DATE(created_at) AS DAY,
      COUNT(*) AS new_added_users
    FROM
      dsv1069.users
    GROUP BY
      DAY
```

Mi pregunta es porque puedo hacer un Count y si quiera hacer un AVG podria? si el tipo de dato fuera correcto ?

```
 ) AS net_added_users FROM (
    SELECT
      DATE(created_at) AS DAY,
      COUNT(*) AS new_added_users
      AVG(*) AS new_added_usersAVG
    FROM
      dsv1069.users
    GROUP BY
      DAY
```

Muchas gracias a todos espero que sea algo realmente simple.

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que `COUNT` tiene una opción de contar la fila usando el asterisco, pero el resto requiere una expresión de un valor escalar. Por lo tanto, puedes usar una columna, una fórmula o una constante (obviamente eso sería inútil para el promedio o valores máximos y mínimos).

En concreto, quedaría algo similar a esto dependiendo de tu tabla y de que valores quieras obtener el promedio.

```
SELECT
  DATE(created_at) AS DAY,
  COUNT(*) AS new_added_users
  AVG( age) AS new_added_usersAVGage
FROM
  dsv1069.users
GROUP BY
  DATE(created_at)
```

Comment: Gracias! fue de mucha ayuda entender esto!